# slick slider responsive slider align items to corners

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I want to make a slick slider showing 3 slides , I want the right slide aligned with the container to the right and the left slides aligned to the left, so the margin between slides need to be dynamic if I change screen width.

[image: current slick slider]

The problem with the example I have is if I add margin between slides they will be no more aligned with the arrows

Comment: Please upload the code or link.

Answer (score 0):

Without a code example it's really hard to help to get an idea.
In css maybe you could use calculate?

https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/